# creating quote in magento open source version 2.0

Tags: quote

Looking for best method to create a quote in Magento Open Source version 2.0. What is best practice method for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a quote in a standalone script and play around you can use:

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();


$quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
$quote = $quoteFactory->create();
```